# BB10 bar submission version number not accepted...but nothing is wrong with the submission

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I have a BB10 Cordova/Webworks app that has had no problems having .bar files created and submitted to BlackBerry World.  The most recent update to my app (1.1.2.1) is prevented from being accepted with the following error:

> The package version in your .bar manifest file for [filename].bar must
>   be greater than the previous version, but lower than any the next
>   release version added to the vendor portal. Your .bar manifest file
>   package version must be greater than 1.1.1.1. Correct your .bar
>   manifest file and try again to continue.

The previous version of my .bar file was submitted with a version
number of 1.1.1.1 and there are no newer versions of the app that has
been uploaded.  The MANIFEST.MF files for the 1.1.2 and 1.1.1 apps are
basically identical except for the version number.

I've tried to re-submit the app with a version number of 10.10.10.10 and yet it is still being denied.

[Other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646464/new-blackberry-app-world-error-bar-manifest-file-package-version-must-be-greate) relate to Android APKs that are being submitted to BlackBerry World and not Webworks .bar files.

Does anyone know whwat is going on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [new blackberry app world error "bar manifest file package version must be greater than ..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646464/new-blackberry-app-world-error-bar-manifest-file-package-version-must-be-greate)

Comment: That question relates to an Android APK that is being submitted to BlackBerry World.  This relates to a .bar file using BlackBerry Webworks.

Comment: change 1.1.2.1 to 1.1.2.2 and try

Comment: This worked...but I don't understand why.  I figured that 10.10.10.10 would be higher than 1.1.2.2.  Either way, post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is with the last digit. if you want to update to a new version, you have to change the digit. ie - if your current version is **1.1.2.1**. so if you want to upload a new build, then you have to set the version number to **1.1.2.2**.

Comment: Worked perfectly.  I think there might have been a change on BlackBerry's side as this was never an issue previously.  Good to know.  BTW, I'd give you an upvote too but my rep isn't high enough.